# Element type is invalid | React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webstorm

I am using WebStorm as my environment. I keep on getting this error every time I try to run the app on the browser:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

This is my code below.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Dashboard from './pages/dashboard';
import Deliveries from './pages/deliveries';
import Promotions from './pages/promotions';
import Inventory from './pages/inventory';
import BusinessHours from './pages/business_hours';
import BankAccount from './pages/bank_account';
import Payments from './pages/payments';
import Employees from './pages/employees';
import RequestDelivery from './pages/request_delivery';
import Support from './pages/support';

function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <Router>
                <Navbar />
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/' exact component={Dashboard} />
                    <Route path='/deliveries' component={Deliveries} />
                    <Route path='/promotions' component={Promotions} />
                    <Route path='/inventory' component={Inventory} />
                    <Route path='/businesshours' component={BusinessHours} />
                    <Route path='/bankaccount' component={BankAccount} />
                    <Route path='/payments' component={Payments} />
                    <Route path='/employees' component={Employees} />
                    <Route path='/requestdelivery' component={RequestDelivery} />
                    <Route path='/support' component={Support} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

[image]

Comment: Which line is pointed at in the error message

Comment: Check the render method of `Router.Consumer`.

Comment: Warning

(34:5) start value has mixed support, consider using flex-start instead

./src/components/Navbar.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/components/Navbar.css)
Warning

(5:5) start value has mixed support, consider using flex-start instead

./src/components/Navbar.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/components/Navbar.css)
Warning

Comment: First of all share the error messages in the question itself instead of comments. Second, share the **Navbar.css** code.

Comment: Warnings are irrelevant for now, let's take care of the error(s) first (so let's not talk about `Navbar.css` just yet). Does every component file exports the class/function component with `export default`?

Answer (score 1):

Check how you are exporting each component. My guess is you are not exporting all of the components as default, meaning you'd have to wrap your imported component around curly brackets.
Another option, you may have forgotten to add export to a component.